# How to replace a single character inside a char array?

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a single character in a char array. I'm just so stuck on how to do this.

```
int addInsert (char *editing_buffer, char to_insert, int pos){

   editing_buffer[pos-1] = to_insert;

}

int main() {
    char string[5] = "ABCDE";
    int r = addInsert(string, "Z", 3);
}
```

I've tried doing it like that, but it shows as an unreadable symbol. This is my first time ever using C, so I'm still not sure entirely what I'm doing.

Comment: Your compiler should be screaming warnings at you for that code. And if not, then enable more warnings. Hint about the problem: Think about the difference between `'Z'` and `"Z"`.

Comment: And if this really is your *first* time with C, then you're way in over your head. Take many steps back, get a couple of good books (or take classes) and *start over* from the very beginning.

Comment: BTW, your question is very poorly formulated, maybe because you don't yet understand what you are doing. Looking back from the code you posted, I'd reformulate along this line: "...how to replace a single character in a C-type string / character array." Your question might be upvoted then.

Comment: Your code does not *add* a character, it replaces an existing one. Very different!

Comment: "but it shows as an unreadable symbol." --> Posted code does not print anything.  See [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your character array initialization is wrong:

```
char string[5] = "ABCDE";
```

You are missing room for the terminating NUL character ('\0').

This

```
char string[6] = "ABCDE";
```

or

```
char string[] = "ABCDE";
```

fixes that problem.

2) *(presuming addInsert() is supposed to be editor_insert_char())* 
You pass the wrong type to your function's second parameter. "Z" is a string (a character array), but your function expects a single character.

Call your function like this, using **single** quotes.:

```
int r = editor_insert_char(string, 'Z', 3);
```

Comment: You're a life saver!! I can't believe my main issue was the quotation marks... thank you so much!!! i can't thank you enough!

Comment: Actually the missing room for the NUL-terminator in your original array definition / initialization is a way more dangerous error as it will lead straight into undefined behaviour land even with simple things like passing that string to printf(). If you are happy with my answer, you can accept it.

Comment: You have missed the most important problem - OP tries to modify string literal, this is UB typically leading to crash

Comment: @qrdl: "*tries to modify string literal*": no, as `string` is a `char` array and not a `char` pointer.

Comment: @qrld As alk already said, you are wrong. Don't confuse beginners with such sloppy answers/comments.

Comment: Sorry, didn't wake up before opening SO :)

Comment: No worries mate...;)

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, but I'd really like to know what is bad about my answer.

Answer (score 0):

your initializer-string for array of chars is too long ,if you define char string[5],you can only use 4 characters or less,use char string[5]="ABCD";instead

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. When I did this the output I got was 'AB�D', the problem I'm having s with this unreadable symbol instead of the letter I'm trying to input?

Comment: "z" is a string,while 'z' is a character,try to use the 'z'

Comment: Initializer-string for array of chars is _not_ too long for legal code.  It simply means `string[]` is not a _string_.

Answer (score 0):

the main issue is that by using double quotes you are passing the `Z` character as a string literal, i.e an array of chars. As `editing_buffer` is a char array, when you want to replace one character with another you will have to pass it like a single character which means you have to use single quotes.

```
"Z" -->  String literal i.e in memory ['Z', '\0']  
'Z' -->  Character i.e ASCII value of Z
```

So basically you were trying to replace a `char` with a `char*`.